# Preventing race condition using the sync.Atomic package in Go

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, atomic, race-condition

I have the following counter implemented in Go that I would like to use in a concurrently. I'm using the atomic package to store the state, but not sure if I could run into any race conditions. Do I need to add an additional mutex as well in order to protect against incrementing below zero for example or do the atomic operations provide enough safety? Thank you!

```
type Counter struct {
    counter  uint64
    finished uint32
    sync.Mutex
}

// Inc increments the counter by one
func (c *Counter) Inc() error {
    if c.isFinished() {
        return fmt.Errorf("counter is finished")
    }

    atomic.AddUint64(&c.counter, 1)
    return nil
}

// Dec decrements the counter by one, but prevents the counter from going to zero
func (c *Counter) Dec() {
    // prevent overflow
    if !c.isZero() {
        atomic.AddUint64(&c.counter, ^uint64(0))
    }
}

// Cancel sets the finished flag, and sets counter to zero
func (c *Counter) Cancel() {
    if !c.isFinished() {
        atomic.StoreUint32(&c.finished, 1)
        atomic.StoreUint64(&c.counter, 0)
    }
}

// isFinished returns true if finished
func (c *Counter) isFinished() bool {
    return atomic.LoadUint32(&c.finished) == uint32(1)
}

// isZero returns true if counter is zero
func (c *Counter) isZero() bool {
    return atomic.LoadUint64(&c.counter) == uint64(0)
}
```

Update: By running the code below with the `-race` flag, I was able to detect that I indeed need to include mutexes.

```
var counter *Counter = &Counter{}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    numberOfLoops := 10
    wg.Add(numberOfLoops)

    for i := 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++ {
        go incrementor(&wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Final Counter:", counter.counter)
}

func incrementor(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        counter.Inc()
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(3)) * time.Millisecond)
    }
    wg.Done()
    counter.Cancel()
}
```

[Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/ml8-vomnnUd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **to avoid races as in "detectable by the race detector"** :

As @caveman answered, the issue you encountered is linked to an issue in `wg.Done() / wg.Wait()` instructions ordering, and the fact that you don't use an `atomic.Load()` to access the value of `counter.counter`.

Your methods are "safe" with regards to this kind of race condition.

- **to avoid races as in "don't reach an incoherent state for counter"** :

you *do* have an issue, (*) because your methods run several successive instructions to inspect and update the object (e.g : `if condition { update_fields }`), and you have no synchronization mechanism to check that the `condition` is still true when you apply `update_fields`.

By changing your `incrementor` function to :

```golang
func incrementor(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i := 0; i < 20000; i++ {
        counter.Inc()
    }
    counter.Cancel()
    wg.Done()
}
```

and running your program several times, you should be able to see that "Final Counter:" does not always end with 0 ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/if35uxOigRR)).

Here is an illustration of how this can occur :

- suppose goroutine 1 executes `counter.Cancel()`
- while goroutine 2 executes `counter.Inc()`

the following sequence of execution may occur :

```
   goroutine 1                                 goroutine 2

                                            1. if c.isFinished() {
                                                   return fmt.Errorf("counter is finished")
                                               }
2. if !c.isFinished() {                         
3.     atomic.StoreUint32(&c.finished, 1)       
4.     atomic.StoreUint64(&c.counter, 0)        
   }                                            
                                            5. atomic.AddUint64(&c.counter, 1)
                                            6. return nil
```

- the `c.isFinished()` instruction in `.Inc()` may happen *before* `.Cancel()` gets executed,
- and the `atomic.AddUint64(&c.counter, 1)` may happen *after* `.Cancel()` has reset the counter to zero.

To avoid this kind of race, you need to choose a way to synchronize the `inspect + update` instructions.

One common way to do that is to use a mutex :

```
type Counter struct {
    counter  uint64
    finished uint32
    m        sync.Mutex
}

// Inc increments the counter by one
func (c *Counter) Inc() error {
    c.m.Lock()
    defer c.m.Unlock()

    if c.finished != 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("counter is finished")
    }

    c.counter++
    return nil
}

// Dec decrements the counter by one, but prevents the counter from going to zero
func (c *Counter) Dec() {
    c.m.Lock()
    defer c.m.Unlock()

    // prevent overflow
    if c.counter > 0 {
        c.counter--
    }
}

// Cancel sets the finished flag, and sets counter to zero
func (c *Counter) Cancel() {
    c.m.Lock()
    defer c.m.Unlock()

    if c.finished == 0 {
        c.finished = 1
        c.counter = 0
    }
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Nba3mfvXTHH)

---

(*) *[edit]* I initially wrote : "because your methods inspect two distinct fields of your object", but you could have a similar issue even with one single field.

For example, if two goroutines run the following code :

```
if c.LoadUint64(&c.counter) == 0 {
   atomic.AddUint64(&c.counter, 1)
}
```

you may have an end value of 2.

The issue lies with having several instructions, which aren't executed in an atomic way.

Comment: Good catch, didn't see that, turns out concurrent programming is hard :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an additional mutex, your main function is reading `counter.counter` without using an atomic load, while your `incrementor` calls `wg.Done()` before `counter.Cancel()`, thus you get a race condition.

By moving `wg.Done()` after `counter.Cancel()` the race condition is resolved:

```golang
func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    numberOfLoops := 10
    wg.Add(numberOfLoops)

    for i := 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++ {
        go incrementor(&wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Final Counter:", counter.counter)
}

func incrementor(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 0; i < 20; i++ {
        counter.Inc()
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(3)) * time.Millisecond)
    }
    counter.Cancel()
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, by atomically loading counter.counter, the race condition is indeed resolved.

Comment: Yes, though, note that by calling `wg.Cancel()` before `counter.Cancel()` you will exit the main goroutine before all `incrementor` goroutines are done. Reading without an atomic load isn't bad, as long as you don't do it concurrently which your wait group guarantees if used correctly :)

Comment: Makes sense, thank you :) Just to clarify, under no circumstance could the following happen: one goroutine calls increment and another one calls cancel at the same time. increment is evaluated and progresses as `finished` is not one. In the meantime, cancel sets `finished` and `counter` to 1 and 0 respectively . After this the execution of `Inc()` is continued, which results in `finished` being 1 and `counter` also equaling 1, an invalid state.

Comment: Well, in theory there is a chance that a routine calls `Add()`, passes then `if c.isFinished()` and then is interrupted by the CPU for whatever reason while another goroutine calls `atomic.StoreUint32(&c.finished, 1)`. Then when `atomic.AddUint64(&c.counter, 1)` is called when the first goroutine gets to it, it  happens after the counter has been canceled. You will likely not catch this at small scales, but it can happend, espcially at large scales. The answer of @LeGEC covers this